# creating custom model on Google vertex ai

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-bucket

I should use Google’s managed ML platform Vertex AI to build an end-to-end machine learning workflow for an internship. Although I completely follow the tutorial, when I run a training job, I see this error message:

```
Training pipeline failed with error message: There are no files under "gs://dps-fuel-bucket/mpg/model" to copy.
```

based on the tutorial, we should not have a /model directory in the bucket. And the model should create this directory and save the final result there.

```
# Export model and save to GCS
model.save(BUCKET + '/mpg/model')
```

I added this directory but still face this error.
Does anybody have any idea, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a pre-built container, ensure that your model artifacts have filenames that exactly match the following examples:

```
TensorFlow SavedModel: saved_model.pb
scikit-learn: model.joblib or model.pkl
XGBoost: model.bst, model.joblib, or model.pkl
```

Reference : [Vertex-AI Model Import](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/general/import-model#:%7E:text=or%20Artifact%20Registry.-,Upload%20model%20artifacts%20to%20Cloud%20Storage,Learn%20more%20about%20exporting%20model%20artifacts%20for%20prediction.,-Import%20a%20model)